# How to add data in listView in android "give me exception"

Tags: android, listview

I use contactPickerIntent to pick user contact 
i want when pick user add the user in listView
the code give me exception

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"
        android:text="Contact" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.99" >
    </ListView>
```

and the activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }


    public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);


    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                // handle contact results
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
                while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterate.next();
                    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
                    System.out.println("-------------LinkedList--------------");
                    dataArray.add((String) extras.get(key));
                }
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a result: "+ result.toString());
                System.out.println(result.toString());


                System.out.println("--------ArrayAdapter-------------------");
                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataArray);
                System.out.println("------------Last----------");
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
            }

        } else {
            // gracefully handle failure
            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
        }
    }
```

this code give me Exception
why give me Exception and what the right way to add data to listview

Comment: What exception? Can you give us more details, like a strack trace?

Comment: what exception u r getting ????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `onCreate(Bundle)` like this way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
}
```

you should find `View` after `setContentView(int)` method.